# Bridge internet connection across subnet

Tags: networking, routing, dd-wrt

I have a Linux box (100.60.120.12, vlan tagged (id:21), default gateway: 100.60.120.11) that I am trying to give internet access to. I cannot change the settings in this Linux box.

I have 2 options - (a) connect the Linux box to a nearby PC that has internet access and somehow use that to provide internet access to the Linux box. (b) Use a router to provide internet access to the Linux box.

I feel option (b) is probably the better way to go. So the setup is:

Linux box <-> tp-link tl-wr841nd running dd-wrt (IP: 192.168.1.2) <-> tp-link Archer (IP: 192.168.1.1, which provides internet access).

I've tried setting vlan options in dd-wrt which allows me to ping 192.168.1.2 from the Linux box. But I cannot ping 192.168.1.1 nor can I ping internet IPs (e.g. 8.8.8.8) -- it says host unreachable).

How can I get internet access to the Linux box?

**Edit - vlan setup and IP addresses**:

[image: VLAN tags]

[image: VLAN Network Config] (MAC removed)

[image: IPs] 100.64.121.12 is on interface eth0.21; rest are on br0.

**Edit 2 - IP route and IP addr info**

Note: I used eth1 as I realised that is the LAN ports. With vlan tag 21 set on eth1, I can ping 100.64.121.11 from the Linux box. But I cannot ping internet IPs. In this state, here is some further info as requested in comments.

```
ip route

100.64.121.0/24 dev eth1.21 scope link  src 100.64.121.11 
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo scope link 
192.168.1.0/24 dev br0 scope link  src 192.168.1.2

ip addr

1: lo:  mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 brd 127.255.255.255 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0:  mtu 1500 qdisc sfq master br0 state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 10:fe:ed:df:f8:3f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth1:  mtu 1500 qdisc sfq master br0 state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 10:fe:ed:df:f8:40 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
11: br0:  mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 10:fe:ed:df:f8:3f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.2/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
12: wlan0:  mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br0 state UP 
    link/ether 10:fe:ed:df:f8:40 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
13: eth1.21@eth1:  mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP 
    link/ether 10:fe:ed:df:f8:40 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 100.64.121.11/24 brd 100.64.121.255 scope global eth1.21
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: I am VERY confused, yes! Have completely re-worded the question.

Comment: Can you show the current VLAN and IP setup you have on DD-WRT (including IP addresses of _all_ interfaces)?

Comment: I think part of the problem here is 100.64.121.11 is NOT a private IP address, or shouldn't be, as it is a bogon address, and you are saying the router has the entire 100.64.121.0/24 subnet locally? "Bogon space IP addresses are not normally visible over the Internet or on any computer network, but they are still exploited, mostly for illegal or fraudulent activities. Hackers manipulate the source IP address to a bogon IP, giving the receiver the impression that the packet is arriving from a reliable source."

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing here, but this is the reason a lot of us are very confused as your setup and intent are unclear, especially when you say you  "cannot change the setting in the Linux box".  Regardless of that, since you can't change the settings in the Linux machine, we would need to know more than it's IP address, we would also need it's subnet mask, gateway setting, DNS settings (maybe), etc. in order to understand why routing isn't working, as DD-WRT should be handling the routing already by default as it's a local subnet

Comment: The Linux box is a piece of hardware that normally connects to a secondary unit which has built in 3G/4G capability. This secondary box gives internet access to the Linux box. In this configuration the Linux box has internet access but I have poor cellular coverage so wanted to use my home broadband to provide access instead. As I understand it, the Linux box's internet traffic is all routed via it's interface with 100.64.121.12/24. The secondary box has an interface with 100.64.121.11. Essentially, I wanted to replicate this with my home network (for faster speed).

Comment: @acejavelin: No, definitely not. For one, 100.64.0.0/10 has been an actual private address range since 2012 when RFC 6598 was published – it's meant to be used in a different place than RFC 1918 addresses, but a private address range nevertheless. Besides that, "bogons" and "not normally visible" is entirely a policy choice – bogon filtering has to be implemented manually, and is only about addresses that the operator knows _aren't_ being used on the network, but if a private network owner _wants_ to use such addresses on their own network, they can perfectly well do that.

Comment: @SimpleOne: For the record though, what you're looking for is _not_ "bridging". A bridge may be involved somewhere, yes, but if traffic goes _across subnets_ then it's IP-level routing (between independent interfaces, i.e. they must not be part of the same bridge for routing to work). I _think_ your "100.64.121.12 is on interface eth0.21; rest are on br0" setup looks about right, but it would be useful to see the actual routing table from `ip route` and the interface list from `ip addr` on DD-WRT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your VLAN configuration seems to be correct, but:

1. The DD-WRT gateway is missing a *default route* (aka default gateway) in its routing table. Without it, it only knows paths to the two directly-attached subnets but not to the rest of the world.

   Configure 192.168.1.1 as the default gateway, so that `ip route` will show:

   ```
   default via 192.168.1.1 dev br0
   ```
2. The Archer gateway is missing a route in the other direction – towards the 100.64.121.0/24 network. Without it, the Linux device can send packets *to* outside but cannot receive anything back.

   Configure a static route to 100.64.121.0/24 through the DD-WRT (specifically via 192.168.1.2 – the address that's facing the Archer).

   If Archer firmware doesn't let you configure static routes, another method – the "duct tape" method – is to enable NAT or masquerading on the DD-WRT (the same kind of NAT that is typically used from LAN to the WAN interface). With NAT enabled, the Archer gateway will only see 192.168.1.2 and not the new network.

Comment: Thanks...this did it!! Bizarrely, tutorials on the net for similar things (different subnets) didn't point to needing to setup the routing.

Comment: Many such tutorials assume you'll be using standard home gateways in their standard "home gateway" configuration, where the default route outbound will be obtained via DHCP and where the "inner" router will do NAT which kind of papers over the lack of an inbound route. (And unfortunately, many home gateway models don't even provide the _option_ to define custom routes in their config UIs, in which case NAT mid-way becomes unavoidable...) In other words, it's the slightly wrong kind of tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The situation:

> I have a Linux box (100.60.120.12, vlan tagged (id:21), default gateway: 100.60.120.11) that I am trying to give internet access to.

> Linux box <-> tp-link tl-wr841nd running dd-wrt (IP: 192.168.1.2) <-> tp-link Archer (IP: 192.168.1.1, which provides internet access).

Step 1:

Connect a cable from a unused LAN port on the DD-WRT unit to your Linux box.

Step 2:

On the DD-WRT box, you need to put that port in its own VLAN.

Step 3:

This will make a new virtual subinterface on the DD-WRT box.  That subinterface It needs the IP address 100.60.120.11 and needs to have the same subnet mask as your Linux box.  Just that subinterface.  It's been a long time since I've messed with DD-WRT so I don't know precisely how to do that, and you may need to create and store a boot script in the device's JFFS2 partition or similar to actually do that.

Basically your router needs 2 LAN interfaces, one for your 192.168.1.x and your 100.60.120.x (assuming your Linux box is a /24, you need to confirm that)

Step 4:

I think it will probably work.

Comment: Thanks, this is essentially what I have tried but it didn't work. My dd-wrt is atheros based so doesn't support port based vlan but does support vlan tagging (from what I've read). Using the setup you describe, I can ping 192.168.1.2 (my dd-wrt) from the Linux box. But I can't ping 'beyond' that - i.e. 192.168.1.1 (my internet modem/router) or DNS 8.8.8.8.

Comment: You don't want to ping 192.168.1.2 on your dd-wrt from the Linux box, you want to ping 100.60.120.11 on your dd-wrt.  Did you try doing https://blog.flashrouters.com/2021/09/29/how-to-config-a-ddwrt-vlan-setup/ or similar to put one of the ports in VLAN 21?  Then you have to assign `eth0.21` the IP 100.60.120.11, probably through ssh.